# php file actionscript computer properties ram processor information

Tags: php, actionscript, ip

I just want to know if there's a way in php that can retrieve the server's properties like computer name, ram, processor information.

Those information will be loaded to an actionscript.

I have done doing a php file in this way to know the server's ip address just like the way it is stated in a tutorial article ove the web:

```
<?php //Opening Tag, tell PHP server to interpret the following lines as php code 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //Sets the ip variable, its value is a method that will get the user ip
echo $ip; //The echo keyword outputs the assigned string, in this case the ip variable 
?>
```

I have done successfully to echo or display the value to my flash application the ip address. Now, what I can't find out is on how to know the server's computer name, ram and processor information.

Is there anyone here know the code in php to show the information I needed?

**EDIT:**
Thank you for fast reply.

Here's the answer. We have to use the exec command. (Considering no security feature has been configured to php or being turned off)

To know the computer's name of a pc.

```
<?php
// outputs the username that owns the running php/httpd process
// (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

For PC's cpu and memory:

```
<?php

function GetProgCpuUsage($program)
 {
     if(!$program) return -1;

    $c_pid = exec("ps aux | grep ".$program." | grep -v grep | grep -v su | awk {'print $3'}");
     return $c_pid;
 }

function GetProgMemUsage($program)
 {
     if(!$program) return -1;

    $c_pid = exec("ps aux | grep ".$program." | grep -v grep | grep -v su | awk {'print $4'}");
     return $c_pid;
 }



    echo "CPU use of Program: ".GetProgCpuUsage($randomprogram)."%";
     echo "Memuse of Program: ".GetProgMemUsage($randomprogram)."%";

?>
```

You can reference more to the source of this info.
 Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: No - but you can invoke programs and read responses or read from pseudo-filesystems which do provide this information - but these are OS specific. (you didn't say what OS this is for).

Comment: Looking at your code, you seem to be trying to re-invent the wheel - most of this stuff is available off-the-shelf under open-source licences - using a much more sensible architecture - e.g. see http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Monitoring-Agents/NRPE--2D-Nagios-Remote-Plugin-Executor/details

Comment: thanks for this idea. I never have known this before. I'll try this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a script in server who will take its hardware information and display it to you. After that call this script via `actionscript` and display the information.

For taking hardware information you requires system command. You have to use `exec` function for running system command.

For taking system information of windows OS use this command `systeminfo`. [System info for windowsOS](http://windowsitpro.com/article/john-savills-windows-faqs/how-can-i-get-system-information-from-the-command-line--23983)